# How to embed a matplotlib plot into a tkinter window, and be able to update the content of the plots, using mouse click events

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to generate a tkinter GUI that does the following:

- contains a matplotlib figure
- can respond to button press events within the figure, and create Line2D objects that connect the points defined by the coordinates of said events. The building of the lines should be immediate; once a button is pressed, this new point is appended to the existing line, and the graph updates accordingly.
- the code should also have the ability to plot/draw more than one line

Points 1 and 3 above are completed, however I am struggling with point 2. The plot never updates after the mouse events, however the coordinates of the events are stored to the Line2D object. You can run this code and see for yourself.

Ive tried using figure.canvas.draw() to redraw the lines I've added/updated to/in the axes object (self.ax in my case) for the figure, but to no avail.

Below is my code for this GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

class gui:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # Miscellaneous Settings
        self.numline = 1
        self.activeline = 1
        self.lines = [Line2D([],[])]

        # Parent widget - widget that all subsequent widgets are added to
        self.frm = ttk.Frame(Tk(), padding=10)
        
        # Making a grid for widgets to be inserted into
        self.frm.grid()
        
        # Initializing StringVar variables
        self.activeLineString = StringVar()
        
        # Adding Buttons
        self.newline = ttk.Button(self.frm, text='New Line', command=self.addline)#, command='function i havent made yet')
        
        # Adding a dropdown menu to select the line ID to edit and/or make active
        self.lineselect = ttk.Combobox(self.frm, textvariable=self.activeline)#.grid(row=2,column=0)
        self.lineselect['values'] = [self.numline]
        
        # Affirmitive comment to tell user exactly what line is being edited
        self.activeLineString.set('Active Line is: {:<2}'.format(self.lineselect.get()))

        # Linking the above stringvar to a label widget
        self.activemessage = Label(self.frm, textvariable=self.activeLineString)

        # Grid layout for all items
        self.newline.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.lineselect.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.activemessage.grid(row=2,column=0)

        # Create basic mpl figure and axes objects
        self.fig,self.ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
        self.fig.dpi = 100
        
        self.ch = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,self.frm)
        self.ch.draw()
        self.ch.get_tk_widget().grid(column=1,row=0,rowspan=15)

        # Binding certain events to class methods
        self.lineselect.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.comboselect)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',self.onclick)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event',self.keypress)
        
        # Main GUI Loop
        self.frm.mainloop()

    def onclick(self,event):
        # edit the data in a 2D list, representing the control points for each path
        aind = self.activeline - 1
        if int(event.button) == 1: #LEFT (1), MIDDLE (2), RIGHT (3) #add point
            print(event.button,event.xdata, event.ydata)
            self.lines[aind].get_xdata().append(event.xdata)
            self.lines[aind].get_ydata().append(event.ydata)
        elif int(event.button) == 3: #delete point
            print('delete cp near here')
        
        # update the graphics of each path in the plot
        # if new line (length of data at this point in code is 1) then ax.add_line
        print(self.lines[aind].get_xdata())
        if len(self.lines[aind].get_xdata()) == 1:
            self.ax.add_line(self.lines[aind])
            print('line added')
        # else, just update the line that already exists on the self.fig.canvas
        print('plot updating')
        print('number of lines in axes: ', len(self.ax.lines))
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
        #self.lines[aind].figure.canvas.draw()
    
    def keypress(self,event):
        if event.key == 'a':
            aind = self.activeline - 1
            self.lines[aind].set_xdata(self.lines[aind].get_xdata().append(event.xdata))
            self.lines[aind].set_ydata(self.lines[aind].get_ydata().append(event.ydata))
        elif event.key == 'd':
            print('removing control point')
        
        self.lines[self.activeline-1].figure.canvas.draw()
    
    def addline(self):
        self.numline += 1
        self.activeline = self.numline
        self.lineselect['values'] += (self.numline,)
        self.lineselect.set(self.lineselect['values'][-1])
        self.activeLineString.set('Active Line is: {:<2}'.format(self.lineselect.get()))

        # add empty list to self.data

    def comboselect(self,event):
        self.activeline = int(self.lineselect.get())
        self.activeLineString.set('Active Line is: {:<2}'.format(self.lineselect.get()))

test = gui()
```

I will admit, that I do not clearly understand how canvases, artists and GUI rendering backends work, so I feel that my efforts past this point wont be worth much. I should also note that this is my first tkinter project, so please excuse my potentially incorrect terminology.

If someone could please provide some insight into how I can make this tkinter-embedded figure automatically update its Line2D content upon button events, or could find a solution to my problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you only updated the internal data of `Line2D` object.(See [the implementation](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.6.2/lib/matplotlib/lines.py#L693) if you are interested. In the `draw()` method, the `self._transformed_path` is used via the `_get_transformed_path()` method and it's derived from the `self._path`, which is created at the `recache()` method) In general, it's not a good idea to modify what a getter method of an object returned to modify the object, because the returned value is usually a copy.

Do like this in the `onclick()`.

```
        ...
        line = self.lines[aind]
        if event.button == 1:
            xdata, ydata = line.get_data() 
            xdata.append(event.xdata)
            ydata.append(event.ydata)
            line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
        ...
```

And as a side note, you don't need to cast an `event.button` to an `int`, and it's better to do `self.ch.draw()` instead of `self.fig.canvas.draw()`.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! Follow up question though, just so that I completely understand the revision. I appended the event point to the data contained in the line object, but did not explicitly set the data to be this updated, appended list of data. When I tested my original logic just using the terminal (i.e. >> x = Line2D([],[]); >> x.get_xdata().append(4); >> x.get_xdata() will return [4]), it seemed to hold/was valid. Why must I explicitly use the set_data() (or set_xdata, set_ydata) methods to update the Line2D object such that it is updated appropriately for the plot?

Comment: I updated the answer for that question.